# How to add a "/" at the end of the URL path?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some urls in my url column.

```
www.quick.com/tea
www.quick.com/tea/green
www.quick.com/tea/green/strong
www.quick.com/tea/black/
www.quick.com/tea/black/light/
```

I need to add "/" at the end of the each urls who are not ending with "/" and need get all the urls in the said column. But this won't return all the data. Can some one help me to get correct data.

```
select concat(url,'/') as url
from table1
RIGHT(url, 1) != '/'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `case` logic:

```
select (case when url like '%/' then url else url || '/' end) as new_url
```

Comment: A common problem with such solution is that a `null` colum gets `'/'`, so the null value should be included in the first `when` predicate.

Comment: It's working, thanks, pls tell me what is the meaning of this " url || '/'  "

Comment: What do you mean by that? pls show me your code? @MarmiteBomber

Comment: @user if `url` is nullable than add `or url is NULL` to the expression: `case when url like '%/' or url is NULL then url ...` this lets `NULL` unchanged, otherwise get `NULL` to a single slash.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber    Got it!

Comment: @user: `||` is the string concatenation operator in SQL

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name ok!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `decode` and `nvl2` functions together

```
with t(url) as
(
 select 'www.quick.com/tea' from dual union all
 select 'www.quick.com/tea/black/light/' from dual union all
 select null from dual   
)    
select nvl2(substr(url,-1),decode(substr(url,-1),'/',url,url||'/'),url) as new_url
  from t;

NEW_URL
------------------------------
www.quick.com/tea/
www.quick.com/tea/black/light/
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/JTMM53583)</kbd>

`nvl2` is applied against the existence of null URLs. Otherwise using `decode(substr(url,-1),'/',url,url||'/')` is enough to derive the `new_url` column.